# How should I configure grub for booting linux kernel from a USB hard drive?

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, usb, grub2

I have a laptop hard drive in an external enclosure which I use as a large pendrive. For an added twist, I have installed Linux on it, so I can boot any machine with my distribution of choice (e.g. for data recovery or repairing a b0rked system or just using a borrowed laptop without destroying the preinstalled Windows).

The problem is that, depending on the hardware configuration, the USB hard drive may be visible under different paths. For grub configuration, I just use `(hda0,0)` as it is relative to the device the grub was launched from. I have UUID entries in `/etc/fstab`. I also specify `rootwait` in the kernel parameters so that it waits for the USB subsystem to settle down before trying to mount the device.

What should I pass to the kernel as `root=`? Currently, boot from the pendrive once, check the debug messages to see what `/dev/sdX` device has been assigned to the USB drive by the kernel, then reboot and edit the grub configuration. I can't change anything on the PC besides enabling `Boot from USB hard drive` in BIOS and setting it to a higher priority than internal hard drives.

There are various initrd generating scripts that include support for UUID in root device path, unfortunately, the Gentoo native one (genkernel) does not support `rootwait` and I had no luck trying to use others.

The boot process goes like this ([it is quite similar in Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process)):

1. The BIOS chooses the boot device and loads whatever is its MBR (which happens to be grub stage-1).
2. Grub loads it's configuration and stage-2 files from the device it has set as `root`, using `(hd0)` for the device it was loaded from by BIOS.
3. Grub loads and starts a kernel (still the same numbering, so I can use `(hd0,0)` again ).
4. The kernel initializes all built-in devices (`rootwait` does it's magic now).
5. The kernel mounts the partition it was passed as `root` (this is a kernel parameter, not grub parameter).
6. `init.d` starts the userland booting process, including mounting things from `/etc/fstab`.

Part 5 is the one giving me problems.

Answer (score 7):

I think the answer should be to use either `root=LABEL=...` or `root=UUID=...`

But you indicate that this doesn't work for you. I would suggest looking into if there is some problem with the actions of your initrd.

Comment: I don't have an initrd, that's the whole problem. genkernel does not support "rootwait" option, and other do not work with Gentoo.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
```

Answer (score 2):

I could be mistaken or possibly just misunderstanding you, but isn't choice of boot device something that would be configured from the BIOS of the machine you're booting?

I would think it would be a matter of choosing the USB drive, which would have GRUB installed as its bootloader, and then choosing which distro you want to boot from the GRUB menu.

Comment: True, but doing it with Grub wouldn't allow him to bypass any BIOS locks ?